# HG How to get commited files only in specific branch

Tags: mercurial

I need to get all committed file in specific branch from command line. Is there any workaround solution for this query? Please let me know what the command to getting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you wish to list all files affected by a certain branch (we'll call it `mybranch` for now). One way to do this is to perform an `hg log` of the branch, and pass it a template which specifies that you just want the affected files listed:

```
hg log -b mybranch --template="{files % '{file}\n'}"
```

For each changeset in the branch, this will list all files affected, separated by a newline.  One downside of this is that if a file is changed in multiple changesets, it will be listed more than once.  You could "fix" this by piping the output into `sort`, and then removing duplicate lines (depending on your system you may have a tool such as `uniq`).

Note that the above will include deleted files in the list - if you don't want that, then you could change the `files` part of the template to include only files modified (`file_mods`) or added (`file_adds`) in the output.  Have a look at `hg help template` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

To print files under Mercurial control you can use `locate`:

```
hg locate -r <branch_name>
```

Comment: Yes all managed files in the branch. What are you looking for?

Comment: No, its not working. In "hg help locate" page,  -r denoted by Revision, not a branch.

Comment: A branch name is a revision. For example `hg log -l1 -r <branch>` will show you the last commit on a branch. It's the same as `hg log -l1 -b <branch>`. You can also use `hg log -r "branch(<branch>)"`.

Comment: Maybe running `hg help revsets` helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
hg manifest -r BRANCH
```